# Autodesk Forge Viewer state properties

Tags: autodesk-forge

How to get the current view eye, target, up and worldvector in the forge?
I am trying to set view data in the database like an IOT RCDB.

Thanks,
Naing Oo

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the camera info from the viewer's navigation object, for example:

- [getPosition](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/navigation/#getposition)
- [getTarget](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/navigation/#gettarget)
- [getAlignedUpVector](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/navigation/#getalignedupvector)

Then you can reapply the camera settings using one of the following nethods:

- [setView](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/navigation/#setview-position-target) for changing the camera immediately
- [setRequestTransition](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/navigation/#setrequesttransition-state-pos-coi-fov-reorient-pivot) (for smoothly transitioning to the new position)